# Template Site not correctly importing fonts and icons

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome, cdn

I have [this](https://www.templatemonster.com/website-templates/58447.html) template site that I need customizing according to customer needs. However it fails to import various fonts and icons correctly.

The style.css file contains these lines to import FontAwesome through a CDN.

```
@import url(//https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:400,700,900);
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700);
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico:400,700);
```

I receive this error upon loading the site:

```
GET file://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico:400,700 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I tried updating the CDN link to the newest version of FontAwesome. The documentation has this guide for fixing the font errors:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACmNt.png

But it did not resolve my issues. I could simply remove the packaged fonts, but I would like to keep them if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `https:` before all the link.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:400,700,900');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico:400,700');
```